# Problemas con restricción "CHECK" en PostgreSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

Tengo problemas al crear la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE contador_eps;

        CREATE TABLE admin_eps(
            id_eps  integer NOT NULL default nextval('contador_eps'),
            nit_eps Integer unique,
            nombre_eps  VARCHAR unique,
            dir_eps  Text,
            ciudad_eps  Text,
            tel_eps  Integer,
            cel_eps  Integer,
            email_eps  text not null unique,
            website_eps Text,
            contacto_eps
            CHECK (email_eps ~*'^\w+@\w+[.]\w+$'),
            PRIMARY KEY (nit_eps, nombre_eps)
```

Me genera este error:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "CHECK"
>           LINE 16:     CHECK (email_eps ~*'^\w+@\w+[.]\w+$')

Que podría estar ocurriendo, en otra base de datos ya me funciono pero, ahora en una nueva BD. me genera error, incluso si retiro la linea del check, con `PRIMARY KEY`, también ocurre el error.

Comment: check tratas de validar para que solo acepte correos electronicos ??

Comment: Si, Claro, que exija el parametro normal ejemplo (nombre@ghhhh.com)

Comment: Para crear el correo electronico

Comment: Solamente para esa columna(email_eps)

Comment: Lo raro en otra BD me funciona bien, pero estoy tratando en una nueva y no quiere aceptar.

Comment: Que versión usabas ahora?

Comment: no falta una coma? despues de contacto_eps? y un tipo de dato?

Comment: He estado trabajando con postgresql 10.1

Comment: Que pena viejo, eso era, siempre me pasa cuando modifico, las columnas, muy amable.